# How to get Parent Custom Attribute value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

i have dynamic Rows of Checkboxes, what i am trying to do is to get Parent Tr Custom attribute value but unable to do so,,i am doing some thing like this

```
   jQuery('[id^="status-"]').click(function(event) {
    var parentTrID = $(this).parent().find('data-tt-id');
    alert(parentTrID);
});
```

and this is my HTML/Php part

```
       <?php
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($this->Allocations as $Allocation)
            {
                $count++;
                ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $count; ?>" data-tt-id="<?php echo $Allocation->getId(); ?>" <?php echo (is_object($Allocation->getParent()) ? 'data-tt-parent-id="' . $Allocation->getParent()->getId() . '"' : ''); ?>>
                    <td><?php echo @$Allocation->getName(); ?></td>
                    <td id="chk"><input type="checkbox" name="status[]" value="<?php echo $Allocation->getId(); ?>"></td>
                    <td><input  type="hidden" id="code-<?php echo $count; ?>" name="code-<?php echo @$Allocation->getCode(); ?>"></td>
                </tr>
            <?php }; ?>
```

Comment: Post the rendered markup. We can't parse your serverside codes with our brains.

Answer (score 2):

you must use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$(this).parent().data('tt-id')
```

Comment: try `jQuery('[name^="status"]').click(function(event) {`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `data()` instead of `find()`, as find is used to find the html element  not the attribute of html element. As you have data attribute you better use data instead of `attr()`

```
 var parentTrID = $(this).closest('tr').data('tt-id');
```

You are binding event on id but you do not have id likr status- but its name to use attribute select for name. Also bind the event in **document.ready** and ensure you have **included** jQuery successfully.

```
jQuery('[name^="status-"]').click(function(event) {
    var parentTrID = $(this).closest('tr').find('data-tt-id');
    alert(parentTrID);
});
```

Comment: The answer suggested `.attr()` with no mention of `.data()` before it was ninja-edited.

Comment: Yes @Juhana, the title of OP caused that.

Comment: @noobie-php, check my edit. You are binding event on id but you do not have id likr status- but its name to use attribute select for name.

Comment: Occasional downvotes are to be expected when you play the fastest gun in the west and answer without reading the question. Surely you knew the reason for the downvote since you then completely revised the answer.

Comment: i still am unable to get value for the desired custom attribute.

Comment: Is event triggered, you need to get to tr, try this, $(this).closest('tr').data('tt-id')

Comment: event is triggered and i am getting [object object] in your Originial edited answer

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with generated html and javascript / Query

Comment: I dont have any idea about fidlle

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you generate this code more than one time right? That means you have multiple `<td id="chk">` elements with the same ID, and that you cannot have. You can check [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/18453687#18453687) about it.

So add some code to generate unique ID's first. (Like `<td id="chk_<?php echo $count; ?>">`)